# Object required 424 error when running macro

Tags: hide, rows

It won't let me ask this question on my other account. I am trying to get this to automatically run when data is inputed into the input cells that are on this sheet. I cannot figure out how to get this macro to auto run without constantly clicking a object.

Secondly, I would like to have this macro run on a protected worksheet. This is what I got so far but it will not auto run when the input cells are  changed and it also gives me an object required 424 error when ever I add the password call to this.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()
'
' hide_cells Macro
' hides journal entry cells
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+Shift+Q
'

Dim c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
UPS_template.Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("K3:K17")
If c.Value = 0 Then
c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next




End Sub
Sub hide_cells()

End Sub
```